# iphone In app purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I'm adding in-app purchase on my application.
I have a view that displays information about the product and one button for purchasing the product.
My question was how can I stop the user to tap again the buy button so that the StoreManager will only call my Buy method once? Because sometimes I had tapped it twice that's why two alertView shows up asking about the purchase. Should I set the button "enabled property" to no after I tap. Any suggestions that would be good about this...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the purchase (after pressing the button) disable the button.

Then you can use the call backs from the store kit API to know when a transaction has completed, failed or otherwise and re-enable the button or change its state to show the fact that the product has been purchased.

Comment: Jasarien, what do you do if the user then taps the 'cancel' button on the alert Apple launches when asking the user for their Apple ID? Is there a way to to handle this? For example, how would you enable the button if the user taps cancel and no interaction with Store Kit occurs?

Comment: I just figured this out. Sorry for the comment. `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is called if the user cancels a purchase and `paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:` is called if the user cancels a purchase restore. Handling those two situations would all for the button to be enabled.